# Ionic - how to display a nearby places list

Tags: typescript, ionic2, ionic3, google-places, google-api-javascript-client

I've been following [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) guide on using Google Place JavaScript library to show a list of restaurants within a 500 metre radius of the hard coded coordinates.

This is what I have attempted so far:

The `.ts` file

```
export class AmenityPage {

  nearbyPlaces: any;
  service: any;
  map: any;

  constructor(){

  }

  init_map(){
    let here = new google.maps.LatLng(-1.3631861,36.6560394);
    let request = {
      location: here,
      radius: [500],
      type: ['restaurant']
    }

    this.service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);
    this.service.nearbySearch(request, this.callback);

  }

  callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      this.nearbyPlaces = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        //let place = results[i];
        this.nearbyPlaces.push(results[i]);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

And here is the `.html` file:

```
<ion-content>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor = "let place of nearbyPlaces">
        <h3>{{place.name}}</h3>
    </ion-item>  
  </ion-list>
 ...

</ion-content>
```

The problem is, no text is displayed when the app is built, neither no errors appear on the console log. I'm not well versed in Ionic, so I haven't got a clue as to what I left out of the code.

Is there a conventional approach to this? Any suggestions and directions on how to solve this is highly appreciated.

Comment: change the lat, lng values or use getCurrentPosition.